# How can I get some specific columns name from laravel table. (not all columns name)

Tags: database, laravel

I need to get columns name from laravel table. but I get all columns name. How can I get some specific columns name that I need from this table?

I have already tried below code to get all columns name:

```
$columnName = DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing('table');
```

It returns `["id","name","email","phone_number","created_at","updated_at"]`
But I am looking for only `["name","email","phone_number"]` not all`("id","created_at","updated_at")` columns. That's what I called specific columns name.

Comment: You should learn about eloquent and relationships in Laravel. udemy.com has some great beginner Laravel tutorials.

Comment: What error you get when you run your code, what you get now?

Comment: You want to *"get some specific columns name"*. What is *specific* for you?

Comment: I did not get any error. this code works fine. but this code returns all columns name, I need some specific columns name form this table. And do not know how to get specific columns name from the laravel table.

Comment: I mean, *specific* could be a column with two or more underscore characters in its name, or so.

Comment: What does you means with "specific"? You already get all columns as array you can just filter them.

Comment: @Tarasovych "get some specific columns name" means find those columns which contains a given sub-string.

Comment: @AnthonyShoshiGomes so you can filter an output. As dparoli told you. Take a look on array filtering functions, or Laravel Collection methods.

Comment: Please update your question detailing the result you want per your comment, if you write good question you will get good answer.

Comment: @dparoli I have updated my question and explain there what I am looking for,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `filter()` function of laravel [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-filter), i.e.:

```php
$columnNames = collect(DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing('table'));
$columnNames = $columnNames->filter(function ($value, $key) {
    return in_array($value, ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at']) === false;
});
```

Comment: It says Call to a member function filter() on array :(

Comment: @AnthonyShoshiGomes you didn't copy all my code the first line is different from your. I use collect(), it returns a collection not an array.